# Two Select option Changes When One select box option changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have 3 select drop down box in my webpage, When i select the options in first select box, then the options of second and third should filter thier options, I have tried a lot, My result is Iam get Change in One select box alone and the other select box is empty. I have given my code below please help me

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#select1").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
/*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
$(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());

} 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[id=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[id=' + id + ']');
$('#select3').html(options);
});
});//]]>  
</script>


<form action="send_request.php" name="myForm1" method="post" onsubmit="return(validate1());">
<select class="regtext sec1test" name="select" id="select1" style="width:99%">
<option value="0">Select What?</option>
<option value="1">Features</option>
<option value="2">Video</option>
<option value="3">Buy1</option>
<option value="4">Buy2</option>
</select>
<div class="sec1 lef" >
    <select name="type" class="regtext sec1test" id="select2" style="width:99%">
    <option id="0" value="0">Select genre</option>

<option value="1" id="1">abc</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">models</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">Comp</option>
    <option value="4" id="4">Beat</option>
    </select>
</div>


<div class="sec1 lef" >
    <select name="type" class="regtext sec1test" id="select3" style="width:99%">
    <option id="0" value="0">Select genre</option>
    <option value="1" id="1">abc</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">mod</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">Comp</option>
    <option value="4" id="4">Beat</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

What is the error in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Note that I'm filtering by `data-id`, `ids` must be unique and are not suitable for this type of functionality.

I dont know the specifics of the inner workings, but I'm pretty sure that this is a byproduct of having duplicate ids and using the filter function.

```js
  var $select1=$("#select1");
  var $select2=$("#select2");
  var $select3=$("#select3");
  $select1.data('options', $select2.html())
  $select1.change(function(){
      var val=$select1.val();
      var options = $($select1.data('options')).filter('[data-id="'+val+'"]');
      $select2.html(options);
      $select3.html(options.clone());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="send_request.php" name="myForm1" method="post" onsubmit="return(validate1());">
  <select class="regtext sec1test" name="select" id="select1" style="width:99%">
    <option value="0">Select What?</option>
    <option value="1">Features</option>
    <option value="2">Video</option>
    <option value="3">Buy1</option>
    <option value="4">Buy2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="sec1 lef">
    <select name="type" class="regtext sec1test" id="select2" style="width:99%">
      <option id="0" value="0">Select genre</option>
      <option value="1" data-id="1">abc</option>
      <option value="2" data-id="2">models</option>
      <option value="3" data-id="3">Comp</option>
      <option value="4" data-id="4">Beat</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="sec1 lef">
    <select name="type" class="regtext sec1test" id="select3" style="width:99%">
      <option id="0" value="0">Select genre</option>
      <option value="1" data-id="1">abc</option>
      <option value="2" data-id="2">mod</option>
      <option value="3" data-id="3">Comp</option>
      <option value="4" data-id="4">Beat</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solutions:

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function() {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);
        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
            var search = $(this).val().trim();
            var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.value.match(regex) !== null) {
                    $(select).append(
                       $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
            if (selectSingleMatch === true && $(select).children().length === 1) {
                $(select).children().get(0).selected = true;
            }
        });            
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('#select2').filterByText($('#select1'), false);
    $('#select3').filterByText($('#select1'), false);
});
```

The plugin was taken from this site:
http://www.lessanvaezi.com/filter-select-list-options/